# asp:TextBox not cooperating with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to fill TextBox on event of two buttons.

```
<div class="numbers-row">
 <div onclick="var result = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = result.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) &amp;&amp; qty > 0 ) result.value--;return false;" class="dec qtybutton"><i class="fa fa-minus">&nbsp;</i></div>

 <asp:TextBox ID="qty" runat="server" class="qty" title="qty" maxlength="12" name="qty"></asp:TextBox>

 <div onclick="var result = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = result.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) result.value++;return false;" class="inc qtybutton"><i class="fa fa-plus">&nbsp;</i></div>
</div>
```

[image: Image contains two buttons. On Onclick event minus button decremented the value and plus button increment the value, but the value is not reflecting on TextBox. But if i use html textbox like <code><input type="text" class="qty" title="Qty" value="1" maxlength="12" id="qty" name="qty"/></code> it works fine]

Image contains two buttons. On Onclick event minus button decremented the value and plus button increment the value, but the value is not reflecting on TextBox. But if i use html textbox like `<input type="text" class="qty" title="Qty" value="1" maxlength="12" id="qty" name="qty"/>` it works fine

Comment: You know it works OK with an `input` tag. What's the `id` attribute of the text box in production? Does it prepend any other info?

Comment: No. TextBox does not contains any other info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.Net chnages the ID of the server controls to ensure unique IDs for elements on a webpage. if you are to use the same ID use ClientIDMode="Static" inside your asp:TextBox. or your may get the input reference in javascript by using

```
document.getElementById('<%=qty.ClientID%>')
```

Comment: Welcome Mohit... you may accept the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, ASP.NET will add additional identifiers to ensure that the ID is unique. When it's rendered on the client the `ID` will look more like `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CustomUserControl1$qty`. You can read more about this naming convention in the [ASP.NET Web Server Control Identification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx)
 docs.

To solve your problem, you can:

- use a CSS attribute selector if you know that the `id` ends with `qty`, like `document.querySelector('[id$="$qty"]')`
- use the exact ID as it is rendered (flakier)
- change the ASP.NET naming convention

Comment: also look into `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your web form control